# Haskell: show that function lines is not the exact reverse of unlines

Tags: haskell

I have to find a few examples that show that the built in Haskell function "unlines" is not the exact reverse of "lines", i.e,

```
unlines.lines x != x
```

where x is a String containing newlines. I found one example for that:

```
"aa\nbb"
```

will become

```
"aa\nbb\n"
```

Does anyone know any other examples, that don't show the same flaw (i.e., unlines always appends a newline after the last line)?

To clearify: According to the automated tests, I already solved the assignment - I simply used the above three times. I'm just interested if there is any other, fundamentally different solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use quickcheck you can find a smaller one:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
main = quickCheck $ \x -> (unlines . lines) x == x
```

It will automatically shrink counterexamples, so it will typically only report the smallest one it finds which is `"a"`.

We can change the property to test only strings ending with `\n`:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
main = quickCheck $ \x0 -> let x = x0 ++ "\n" in (unlines . lines) x == x
```

I did not find any counterexamples.

You might also be interested in testing the other direction, `(lines . unlines)`. Excluding cases where one of the strings contain a newline, this property holds.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence, there are probably "round-trip-and-a-half" laws like `lines . unlines . lines == lines` and `unlines . lines . unlines == unlines`.